# Making scrollbar invisible without removing it - Windows browser

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In my Angularjs app I have a dropdown menu that appears when I click on a link. To stop scrolling on the page while the menu is showing I use `overflow:hidden` and add the class to the body when the menu is showing:

However, using `overflow:hidden` also removes the vertical scrollbar completely from Windows based browsers meaning the whole page shifts to the right (by the width of the scrollbar) when the menu opens.

Can I stop the scrolling without completely removing the scrollbar? Perhaps keep the scrollbar container in place but hide the handle.

**Example**
Take a look at https://fancy.com/ - click on the login link and the modal should appear. The scrollbar handle disappears but the scrollbar container remains. How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: You can add margin-right to body when overflow is hidden

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't have the desired effect. The page still moves to the right.

Comment: I've added an example of the desired effect.

Comment: Used some nested divs. Have `overflow-y:scroll;` set to the parent div and toggle `overflow:hidden;` along with `width:100%;height:100%;` on the child div.

Comment: So the parent container should be the `body` and then have an immediate `div` inside as a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take a look at https://fancy.com/ - click on the login link and the modal should appear. The scrollbar handle disappears but the scrollbar container remains. How can I achieve this effect?

Looks like they are simply doing this by having `overflow-y: scroll` set for `body` to begin with, and then a class `fixed` is added to the `html` element when you click “login”.

And then that class affects the main content container of the page, setting it to fixed position:

```
.fixed #container-wrapper {position:fixed;left:0;width:100%; /*[…]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the menu into a wrapper div and set `overflow-x:` and `overflow-y:` as you need for this div.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, this can easily be done with nested divs. Yes it could be done using the `body` tag but that is a very simple change from my code below. You can see the effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/udgj3ot5/

*Note:* I doubt you will be calling the function straight from the child div so another means to pointing to the element other than `this` will probably need to be used.

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
div.parentDiv { /*Set this to the body if you don't want two divs*/
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function toggleChildDiv(elem) {
    if (elem.style.overflow == "hidden") {
    elem.style.width = "auto";
    elem.style.height = "auto";
    elem.style.overflow = "visible"
  } else {
    elem.style.width = "100%";
    elem.style.height = "100%";
    elem.style.overflow = "hidden"
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div onclick="toggleChildDiv(this)">
    YOUR PAGE CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```